# how to maintain state for a table in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to upload a csv file data to DB.
the process is like :

i am extracting csv file data to DataTable.

validating DataTable fields .
if all good , loading them into DB on button click.

i am generating invTable at below validation method by passing saved csv file path on validate button click.

```
protected void ValidateData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ValidateCsv();
}

private void ValidateCsv(string fileContent)
{

    DataTable getCSVData;
    getCSVData = GetData(fileContent);
    invTable= Validate(getCSVData);
}
```

if am loading it on BulkUpload_Click, invTable is null.
ideally it should have data , as assinged in ValidateCsv method.

```
  protected void BulkUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MatchedRecords(invTable);
    }
```

any idea how to maintain invTable data across postback?

Comment: "any idea how to maintain invTable data across postback?" Consider adding what happened, like did your table disappear? After when?

Comment: @CurseStacker yep, MatchedRecords(invTable);the invTable is getting null.

Comment: Edit your question and detail it from there. What line of code references the invTable and returning the null error?

Comment: @CurseStacker, just edited it.

Comment: where is your invTable declared?

Comment: variables don't persist between postbacks unless they're server controls (e.g textboxes etc) and that's only as long as you haven't disabled ViewState. For everything else, you'd have to store it in the session, if it's not too large, or persist it to a disk or database, or re-initialise it from the postback data, if it could have been modified by the user. What type of object is invData?

Comment: @ADyson Ok, invData basically contains row and columns.which will be static once uploaded through CSV file.

Comment: I didn't ask that, I asked what is the _type_ of invData? Is it a DataTable, a string, a List<T>, what is it? Is it a server control (e.g. GridView, Repeater or something)? The distinction is important so we know whether it should have been persisted by the ViewState or not.

Comment: sorry,its a DataTable.

Comment: in that case, for it to exist again after another postback you have to manage the persistence yourself. I mentioned some of your options in my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `ValidateCsv` to a function.

```
private DataTable ValidateCsv(string fileContent)
{

    DataTable getCSVData;
    getCSVData = GetData(fileContent);
    invTable = Validate(getCSVData);

    return invTable;
}
```

Then on your `MatchedRecords`, modify it to accept a `DataTable` parameter.

```
private void MatchedRecords(DataTable invTable) {

}
```

Then on your `BulkUpload_Click` event, reference to the `ValidateCsv`, now a function that returns the value of your `DataTable` to the `MatchedRecords` void.

```
protected void BulkUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MatchedRecords(ValidateCsv('enter how you get the fileContent here...'));
}
```

Or

```
protected void BulkUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable valueTable = ValidateCsv('enter how you get the fileContent here...');
    MatchedRecords(valueTable);
}
```

Comment: thanks ,yep this is the other way around.ValidateCsv also call GetData and Validate method .so will it be a good design ? i mean nesting of many method?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's the best design, but functions are made to be called, so I don't see any problem with calling it from inside another function.